# Equivalent merge output in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

I am learning oracle sql and pl/sql and I wonder if there is equivalent clause 'merge=output' in Oracle or easy and effective way to have the same result.

Link to good explonation of sql server 'merge,output' stetment.
[link](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/06/using-the-output-clause-with-t-sql-merge/)

```
--sql server merge
    MERGE  #c_new AS trg
     USING #c_base AS src
        ON trg.Num_id = src.Num_id
    WHEN MATCHED )
    THEN
       UPDATE SET
          trg.Name = src.Name
         ,trg.Name_type = src.Name_type
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY trg
    THEN
       INSERT (Num_id, Name, Name_type)
       VALUES (Num_id, src.Name, src.Name_type)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY src THEN DELETE
    ------------output clause from here---------------
     OUTPUT
       $ACTION,
       inserted.Name   NewName,
       deleted.Name    PrevName,
       inserted.Name_type  NewName_type,
       deleted.Name_type  PrevName_type
```

Return (like 'query')

```
$action  NewName  PrevName  NewName_type  PrevName_type
INSERT   Abc1               Tp1
DELETE            Abc2                    Tp2
UPDATE   Abc4     Abc3      Tp4           Tp3
```

Is it equivalent clause 'merge=output' in Oracle or easy and effective way to have the same result

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: my question is about oracle syntax i know more or less how to implement efect like merge output from sql server but i don't finding information if in oracle exist clausle outup in merge or simple way to do that. I can add sample data but i don't think is a good way to fix on data. In added link is exposed form of return data from merge output stetment sql server

Comment: I have no idea what that "merge output" is supposed to be (and probably many other people using Oracle don't either). You need to tell us what problem you are trying to solve. It could be that the approach you took in SQL Server is either not available in Oracle, or that problem can be solved in a completely different way in Oracle. And the best way to do that is to describe the actual problem and illustrate that with an example. You can't expect people proficient with Oracle to **also** know everything about SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, i add some data but in my opinion if you lerning and ask about syntax is a bad way to prepare sample dummy problem because 'statment' can be used in very different way. Additionally, I think Oracle 'specjalist' do not need to know everything about sql server, but for someone who is in touch with programming find and understand 'merge, output from sql server' It will not take more than that 2 minutes in base version :)

Comment: DML statements don't return result sets in Oracle. It sounds like a neat feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest Oracle equivalent I know of is the RETURNING clause, but apparently not supported for MERGE statements:

> "Yes, returning into is not supported for merge [...] If you want this
>   functionality, submit an enhancement request"

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9528727800346317168

The current doco does reference being able to log the errors, but that's clearly not quite what you (or I) are after :-(

> The error_logging_clause lets you capture DML errors and the log
>   column values of the affected rows and save them in an error logging
>   table.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F